# Read bits from uint32_t

Tags: c++, endianness, uint32-t

I want to use a function that returns a `uint32_t` which is supposed to contain 8 bits of information, in little-endian format. Could someone give me some C++ code on how to extract these bits from the `uint32_t` type into chars, booleans or into any other type that does not need the use of the Force to deal with! Because right now I do not have the patience to understand the whole concept of endianess. And the more I *shallowly* search the more complicated it seems...

PS. Although not what I am looking for, if someone could also post some code on how one could encode 8 bits (ex. 8 booleans) in an `uint32_t` would be interesting as I think it would help me understand the concept.

Answer (score 2):

A sample in C, using `union` to force both an integer and combined bit values in the same address space, and with bitfields `b0..b7` to hold single bit values:

```
#include <stdio.h>

union Bitfields {
    unsigned int as_int;
    struct {
        unsigned char b0:1,b1:1,b2:1,b3:1,
        b4:1,b5:1,b6:1,b7:1;
    } as_bit;
};

int main (void)
{
    Bitfields bitfield;

    bitfield.as_int = 73;

    printf ("%u %u %u\n", bitfield.as_int, bitfield.as_bit.b0, bitfield.as_bit.b1);

    return 0;
}
```

This allows easy read/write access to both the integer value and each one of your separate bits, whatever is more convenient.

Answer (score 0):

Little endian means that the bytes that make up the uint32_t have the least significant byte stored at the lowest memory address and the most significant at the highest. Endian-ness should not enter the picture when extracting bits. It only enters the picture if you are doing things like accessing a uint32_t variable through a char *.

```c
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdint>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    unsigned char ch;
    uint32_t u32;
    bool b0, b1, b2, b3, b4, b5, b6, b7;

    // If the 8 bits you need are the least significant ones then getting
    // them is as easy as:
    u32 = 73;
    ch = u32 & 0xFF;
    cout << ch << endl;

    // To encode boolean variables is just as easy:
    b0 = b1 = b3 = b5 = 0;
    b2 = b4 = b6 = b7 = 1;
    u32 = (b0 << 0) | (b1 << 1) | (b2 << 2) | (b3 << 3) | (b4 << 4) |
        (b5 << 5) | (b6 << 6) | (b7 << 7);
    cout << hex << u32 << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Endianness deals with **memory loads/stores** and not *values*

When accessing a variable, it will be loaded from memory using the default endianness of the system (little endian in the case of x86) and give you the correct *value* in the variable. Therefore if you want the 8 low bits, just apply a mask and get that value

```
x = someint32 & 0xff;
```

Likewise, assigning a `char` into an `int` or using it in an expression will just copy its *values*. The bit pattern will be sign-extended or zero-extended depending on the signness of the type, but you're still dealing with only values. Endianness is irrelevant here because there's no memory access